# How to manage 'Like' button for URLs that can change slightly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a like button on each page in a wallpaper site. There is an option to edit the title of the wallpaper. Hence, the URL of the page changes as well, like it happens in Stack Overflow. In Stack Overflow, when the title of the question changes, the old URL is redirected permanently to the new URL. The same logic is implemented in my site.

The problem is, say if there are 10 likes for a wallpaper page

> http://www.example.com/1/old-title-wallpaper

If the title is changed slightly to 'new title', the URL changes to

> http://www.example.com/1/new-title-wallpaper

In the new page, the like count becomes 0. Is there a way to make the Like button detect 301 redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The like button uses the og:url tag. On your new page you need to keep the old og:url value.

Answer (score 1):

This means you are not giving an explicit url for the like button code..
Hence the FB server picks the current url of the page where the like button is placed..
Check the iFrame of like button and see that you mention the data-href there ..
Sample Code:

```
`<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {

     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxxx0&xfbml=1";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
   (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://xxx.com" data-send="true" data-width="450"    data-show-faces="true">
  </div>
```

Link to Like Pluggin
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Also, you can use Metadata tags to explicitly make the FB server pick the url as desired by you .. Use Open Graph tag og:url for that 
See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/