# .htaccess or php redirect to friendly url when index.php?*=* is accessed directly

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

i am working on a new design for my gaming site, and what i have done is made a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^play/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?play=$1 [L]
```

this works perfectly, when a user opens /play/gamename that stays in the address bar (canonical url) and it loads the game page using my index.php.

however, what i want to do now, is that when a user access the old url (`index.php?play=gamename`) they should get redirected to the new canonical url (`/play/gamename`).

could someone please type up the code for me to do this? i am open to both doing this with the .htaccess file or the index.php file, whichever works best.

another problem is that i already have a lot of facebook comments and likes, which refer to the `index.php?play=gamename` pages, would it also be possible to somehow move these likes and comments to the new prettier urls?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be looking for something like this to redirect from your old URL to your new URL while also maintaining that URL as the actual place the script is served from.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Stop rewrite from doing an infinite loop by rejecting redirects
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^play=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /play/%1? [NC,R=301,L]

# Rewrite all requests from /play/ to index.php
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)$ /index.php?play=$1 [NC,L]
```

As for facebook, there is nothing you can do about old comments, but your rewrite will take care of that for any future clicks through to your site.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this in php would be as follows:

This function checks if the page is being directly viewed.

```
function directviewcheck(){
    $requestingurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $phpselflength = strlen($phpself);
    $resulturlcrop = mb_substr($requestingurl, 0, $phpselflength);

    if( $resulturlcrop == $phpself ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

That will tell you if the url in the browser matches the file name. And if it does it will return true.

Next call it in index.php:

```
if( directviewcheck() == true ){
    // your redirect code
    // Something like this should work

    $gamename = $_GET['play'];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently")
    header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/play/" . $gamename );
    exit;  // make sure you use exit or its alias die to prevent the page from showing.

}
```

The old links would go to the new page, and Search engines that still reach your content on the old links would know to drop them and index the new links.

You could make a location variable if you need it to be more dynamic and then drop it in the header() depending on the use.

Anyway, your question is old but perhaps still useful to you or someone else.

====

In .htaccess sjdaws looks to work.

====

Far as your Facebook I saw these:
[Facebook like count resets after a 301 redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691311/facebook-like-count-resets-after-a-301-redirection)
or
[How to manage 'Like' button for URLs that can change slightly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425192/how-to-manage-like-button-for-urls-that-can-change-slightly)